# The Great Science-Fiction/Fantasy TV Showdown! (Round 1) [Finished!]

Tags: discussion, contest, prizes

### The first round is over! Results and Round Two can be seen [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9546/the-great-science-fiction-fantasy-tv-showdown-round-2/9547#9547)!

Who's up for The Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange's own (slightly belated) version of March Madness?

For all the info, see [here](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/04/the-great-science-fictionfantasy-tv-showdown/).

Here's how to participate:

I will post two answers to this question.

One will be for voting. It will have all 24 primary brackets on it. Any site member with a SF&F SE account older than two weeks as of 4/25/2016 may vote. To do so, **simply leave a single comment with the 24 shows you think are better.** Put *Pass* and the bracket's number if you don't want to vote on a specific bracket. Attempting to vote more than once will result in *none* of your votes counting. At 6pm ET, in exactly one week, voting will close. I will see which 24 shows won their brackets and will post an update for Week Two.

The other answer will be for predicting the winner. This week only, any member with a SF&F SE account older than two weeks as of 4/25/2016 may comment their prediction on the answer. I will record all the predictions and will have a raffle for all the correct ones. The winner will receive a 100 rep bounty on their best site answer, as determined by me.

**Please do not leave an answer on this page. If you have an additional question, comment, or gripe that your favorite show isn't on the list, please comment on the main question, not either of the answers.**

You can chat about the event [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38884/the-great-science-fiction-fantasy-tv-showdown-discussion-room).

Have fun and May the Force be with you/ Live long and prosper/ Keep Flying/ Live together, die alone/ Cowabunga!/ Fear the Living, Fight the Dead...

And remember, choose wisely!

[image]

Comment: Why the "account older than two weeks" restriction? IMO it would make more sense to have a rep-based restriction, since you need at least 50 (?) rep to post comments anyway.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I want to prevent the (highly unlikely) creation of multiple accounts solely to vote for people's favorite shows.

Comment: What winner are we guessing on? The final result after all rounds?

Comment: I think anaranjada's model is better for answering the votes : "_1. The Next Generation, 3. My Little Pony, 5. Nu-Who, 23. Quantum Leap, 24. Firefly. Pass on the rest._"

Comment: Where is *I Dream of Jeannie*? Where is *Lexx*?

Comment: @creationedge Yes, the final winner.

Comment: Whoever's voting to close this, I got explicit permission from multiple moderators.

Comment: You need to post the actual bracket now, *before* we know the outcome of the first round. As in, which matchup's winner will compete with the winner of the Star Trek matchup? Do we go with the next one on the list, i.e. *Futurama/Rick and Morty*, or did you have something more evenly-matched (and less apples and Ferraris) in mind?

Comment: Also, is there some way to distinguish between *Pass* = I have no clue what these shows are vs. *Pass* = both of these shows suck? Or for that matter, is there some way to give extra weight to "I vote for **A** because it's a vastly superior show to **B**" vs. "I vote for **A** because I've never heard of **B**" vs. "I vote for **A** because, although I've never heard of it, it had to be better than **B**, which was one of the worst things on TV"?

Comment: @Martha You're overcomplicating it ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor: um, yes, so? :) (And is that in reply to my wish to distinguish the different possible meanings behind a particular choice, or a reply to my desire to see the entire bracket mapped out ahead of time? Because the latter just seems like basic fairness. Also, we can't make a realistic guess at a winner without it.)

Comment: @Martha That was in reply to your wish to distinguish between different kinds of votes and passes. Yes, it'd be a nice thing to do, but it's already hard enough to make some of these choices - if we complicated it like that, fewer people would bother voting :-) To your first question, I suspect the answer is that RJ will choose new pairings based on which shows emerge as the winners in the first round. The pairings we have already were chosen by RoJal decree, after all ...

Comment: @user14111 : I second that --- where is *Lexx*??

Comment: Also, I feel *X-Files / Fringe* is a better head-to-head than *LOST / X-Files*, imho.  (But I'm happy we're doing this, regardless!)

Comment: I like the idea of new initiatives and this is very creative. I'm just missing the "why?" Why are we doing this? Why should we participate? [It could also be my FUN subroutine has been deleted.]

Comment: @Wikis Several reasons. 1. To [do this](http://www.memegen.com/meme/i84nb9). 2. To see what properties are more and most popular with the site's membership. 3. To encourage regularly visiting the site.

Comment: I guess I missed participating in this. A week might have been a little short. Oh well. Also, you're missing the best realistic SF show ever made: Jericho. Or maybe that's so realistic that it's just fiction...

Comment: @DCShannon Don't worry! You can still enter [Round 2](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9546/the-great-science-fiction-fantasy-tv-showdown-round-2/9547#9547).

Answer (score 6):

### VOTE ([Here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9546/the-great-science-fiction-fantasy-tv-showdown-round-2?noredirect=1#comment25886_9546))!

1. Trek Yourself Before You Wreck Yourself: *Star Trek: The Original
   Series* / *Star Trek: The Next Generation*
2. Not Your Children’s’ Cartoons: *Futurama* / *Rick and Morty*
3. Fun For All Ages: *Adventure Time* / *My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic*
4. The Family That Slays Together: *Buffy the Vampire Slayer* / *Angel*
5. Who Are You? Who, Who, Who, Who?: Classic *Doctor Who* / Nu-Who
6. The Element Of Surprise: *Avatar: The Last Airbender* / *The Legend of
   Korra*
7. Mysteries And Stuff: *LOST* / *X-Files*
8. Batman V Batman: Dawn of Batman: *Batman* (‘60s) / *Batman: The
   Animated Series*
9. What A Twist!: *The Twilight Zone* (Original) / *The Outer Limits*
   (Original)
10. Jedi Did Not See That Coming: *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* / *Star
     Wars: Rebels*
11. Turtle Power!: TMNT (Original)  / TMNT (2012)
12. No Spoilers!: *Game of Thrones* / *The Walking Dead*
13. Space And Stuff: *Battlestar Galactica* (2004) / *Babylon 5*
14. DC on CW: *Arrow* / *The Flash* (2014)
15. This IS A Place For A Hero: *The Spectacular Spider-Man* / *Justice
     League Unlimited*
16. Aussies and Brits: *Farscape / Red Dwarf*
17. Simply Marvelous: *Marvel’s Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D* / *Daredevil*
18. Currently Airing Fantasy: *Supernatural* / *Once Upon a Time*
19. The Spin-Offs: Stargate: *SG-1* / *The Sarah Connor Chronicles*
20. The Classics: *The Incredible Hulk* (1978) / *The Hitchhiker’s Guide
     to the Galaxy* (TV series)
21. Animation Across The Nation(s): *Transformers* (1984) / *Gravity Falls*
22. Pretty Funny: *Sabrina the Teenage Witch* / *ALF*
23. Time After Time: *Quantum Leap* / *Torchwood*
24. There Are Two Left Over And I Can’t Think Of Any Connection But
     They Both Start With F, So Let’s Go With That: *Firefly* / *Fringe*

Comment: **MODEL COMMENT:** 1. Star Trek: The Original Series, 2.  *Pass*, 3. *Pass*, 4. *Pass*, 5. Nu-Who, 6. Avatar the Last Airbender, 7. LOST, 8. Batman (60's), 9. The Twilight Zone, 10. Star Wars: The Clone Wars. 11. TMNT (2012), 12. *Pass*, 13. *Pass*, 14. *Pass*, 15. The Spectacular Spiderman, 16. *Pass*, 17. Daredevil, 18. *Pass*, 19. *Pass*, 20. The Incredible Hulk, 21. Gravity Falls, 22. *Pass*, 23. Quantum Leap, 24. Firefly

Comment: 1.Star Trek: The Next Generation, 2.Futurama, 3.Adventure Time, 4. Buffy the Vampire Slayer, 5. Nu-Who
6. Avatar: The Last Airbender, 7. Pass,
8. Batman: The Animated Series, 9. The Twilight Zone (Original), 10. Pass, 11. TMNT (Original), 12. The Walking Dead, 13. Pass, 14. Arrow, 15: Justice League Unlimited, 16.
Farscape, 17. Pass, 18. Supernatural,
19. Stargate: SG-1, 
20. The Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Galaxy (TV series), 21. Transformers (1984), 22. Sabrina the Teenage Witch, 23. Torchwood, 24.
Firefly.

Comment: 1. Star Trek: The Next Generation, 2. Futurama, 3. Pass, 4. Angel, 5. Nu-Who, 6. Pass, 7. X-Files, 8. Batman: The Animated Series, 9. Pass, 10. Pass, 11. TMNT (Original), 12. Game of Thrones, 13. Pass, 14. Arrow, 15. Pass, 16. Pass, 17. Daredevil, 18. Supernatural, 19. Pass, 20. Pass, 21. Pass, 22. Sabrina the Teenage Witch, 23. Quantum Leap, 24. Firefly.

Comment: 1. Pass 2. Rick and Morty 3-7. Pass.  8. Batman (60's) 9. Twilight Zone 10. Pass 11. TMNT (2012) 12. The Walking Dead 13-19. Pass 20. Hulk 21. Transformers 22. ALF 23. Quantum Leap 24. Pass

Comment: 1. TOS 2. Rick and Morty 3. My Little Pony 4. Angel 5. Nu-Who 6. The Last Airbender 7. X-Files 8. Batman: TAS 9. The Twilight Zone 10. The Clone Wars 11. TMNT (Original) 12. The Walking Dead 13. Galactica 14. The Flash 15. Justice League Unlimited 16. Farscape 17. Daredevil (Netflix) 18. Supernatural 19. SG-1 20. Hitchhikers Guide 21. Transformers 22. ALF 23. Torchwood 24. Fringe

Comment: 1. Star Trek: The Next Generation, 2. *Pass*, 3. My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic, 4. Angel, 5. Nu-Who, 6. The Legend of Korra, 7. X-Files, 8. Batman: The Animated Series, 9. The Twilight Zone, 10. Star Wars: The Clone Wars, 11. *Pass*, 12. Game of Thrones, 13. Battlestar Galactica, 14. Arrow, 15. Justice League Unlimited, 16. Farscape, 17. Daredevil, 18. Once Upon a Time, 19. The Sarah Connor Chronicles, 20. The Incredible Hulk, 21. Gravity Falls, 22. Sabrina The Teenage Witch, 23. Torchwood, 24. Firefly

Comment: 1. The Next Generation, 3. My Little Pony, 5. Nu-Who, 23. Quantum Leap, 24. Firefly. Pass on the rest.

Comment: 1. TNG
2. Futurama
3. Pass
4. Angel
5. Modern Who
6. OMG IDK! Korra! 
7. X-Files
8. B:TaS
9. TZ
10. Clone Wars
11. Movies? TMNT 2012
12. TWD
13. BSG
14. The Flash
15. JLU
16. Farscape
17. Daredevil
18. Supernatural
19. SG-1
20. Pass
21. Pass.
22. Sabrina
23. Torchwood
24. Fringe (sorry, I <3 FF, but Fringe actually got more than 1 season...)

Comment: 1. Star Trek: The next generation. 2. Pass. 3. Pass. 4. Angel. 5.  Pass. 6. Avatar: The Last airbender. 7. X-files. 8. Pass. 9. Pass. 10. Star wars: The Clone wars. 11. TMNT (Original). 12. The Walking dead. 13. Battlestar Galactica. 14. Arrow. 15. Pass. 16. Pass. 17. Agents of shield. 18. Supernatural. 19. SG1. 20. Pass. 21. Pass. 22. ALF. 23. Pass. 24. Firefly

Comment: 1. Pass 2. Futurama 3. Adventure Time 4. Buffy 5. Pass 6. Pass 7. Lost 8. Batman: TAS 9. Pass 10. Pass 11. TMNT (Original) 12. Game of Thrones 13. Battlestar Galactica 14. Arrow 15. Justice League Unlimited 16. Pass 17. Daredevil 18. Supernatural 19. SG1 20. Pass 21. Pass 22. Sabrina 23. Pass 24. Fringe

Comment: 1. Pass 2. Pass 3. Pass 4. Pass 5. Pass 6. Pass 7. Pass 8. Pass 9. Pass 10. Pass 11. Pass 12. Pass 13. Pass 14. Pass 15. Pass 16. Pass 17. Pass 18. Pass 19. Pass 20. Pass 21. Pass 22. Pass 23. Pass 24. Pass

Comment: 1. New Doctor Who!

Comment: 1. Star Trek: The Next Generation, 2. Futurama, 3. My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic, 4. Buffy the Vampire Slayer, 5. Nu-Who, 6. The Legend of Korra, 7. X-Files, 8. Batman: The Animated Series, 9. The Outer Limits (Original), 10. Star Wars: The Clone Wars, 11. TMNT (2012), 13. Babylon 5, 14. The Flash (2014), 15. Justice League Unlimited, 16. Farscape, 17. Marvel’s Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D, 18. Once Upon a Time, 19. Stargate: SG-1, 20. The Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Galaxy (TV series), 21. Gravity Falls, 22. Sabrina the Teenage Witch, 23. Quantum Leap, 24. Firefly

Comment: 10. Star Wars: Rebels, 14. The Flash (2014), 17. Daredevil, 24. Firefly. *Pass on the rest.*

Comment: 1. TOS, 2. Futurama, 3. Adventure Time, 4. Angel, 5. Nu-Who (*as much as I enjoy Classic Who, Nu-Who is better), 6. The Last Airbender, 7. X-Files, 8. Batman: The Animated Series, 9. The Outer Limits (Original), 10. Star Wars: The Clone Wars, 11. TMNT (Original), 13. Babylon 5, 14. The Flash (2014), 15. Justice League Unlimited, 16. Red Dwarf (*Farscape is probably better, but going with British pride), 17. PASS, 18. PASS, 19. Stargate: SG-1, 20. The Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Galaxy (TV series), 21. Transformers (1984), 22. ALF, 23. Quantum Leap, 24. Fringe.

Comment: 1. Next Generation, 2. *Pass*, 3. Friendship is Magic, 4. Buffy, 5. Nu-Who, 6. *Pass*, 7. *Pass*, 8. The Animated Series, 9. *Pass*, 10. *Pass*, 11. *Pass*, 12. Thrones, 13. Babylon 5, 14. *Pass*, 15. *Pass*, 16. Farscape, 17. Agents of Shield, 18. Once Upon a Time, 19. Stargate SG-1, 20. *Pass*, 21. *Pass*, 22. Sabrina, 23. Torchwood, 24. Firefly Firefly Firefly Firefly Firefly... *I suppose it would be mean to fill up the rest of my 150 characters with "Firefly"...*

Comment: 1. TNG 2. Rick & Morty 3. Pass 4. Buffy 5. Nu 6. Pass 7. Pass 8. TAS 9. The Twilight Zone 10. Pass 11. Pass 12. GoT 13. Babylon 5 14. The Flash 15. JLU 16. Farscape 17. Daredevil 18. Pass 19. SG-1 20. Hitchhiker’s 21. Transformers 22. Pass 23. Torchwood 24. Firefly

Comment: 1. Star Trek: The Next Generation
2. Futurama
3. Pass
4. Buffy the Vampire Slayer
5. Nu-Who
6. Avatar: The Last Airbender
7. Pass
8. Pass
9. The Outer Limits (Original)
10. Star Wars: Rebels
11. TMNT (Original)
12. Game of Thrones
13. Babylon 5
14. Pass
15. Pass
16. Red Dwarf
17. Marvel’s Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D
18. Pass
19. Stargate: SG-1
20. The Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Galaxy (TV series)
21. Transformers (1984)
22. Sabrina the Teenage Witch
23. Quantum Leap
24. Firefly

Comment: 1. Star Trek: The Next Generation, 2. Futurama, 3. My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic, 4. Angel, 5. Nu-Who, 6. Avatar: The Last Airbender, 7. X-Files, 8. Batman: The Animated Series, 9. The Twilight Zone (Original), 10. Star Wars: The Clone Wars, 11. TMNT (2012), 12. Game of Thrones, 13. Battlestar alactica (2004), 14. The Flash (2014), 15. Justice League Unlimited, 16. Red Dwarf, 17. Daredevil, 18. Pass, 19. Pass, 20. The Incredible Hulk 1978), 21. Transformers (1984), 22. ALF, 23. Quantum Leap, 24. Firefly

Comment: 1. Star Trek: The Original Series, 2. Futurama, 3. _Pass_, 4. Buffy the Vampire Slayer, 5. Classic Doctor Who, 6. _Pass_, 7. X-Files, 8. Batman: The Animated Series, 9. The Twilight Zone (Original), 10. The Clone Wars, 11. _Pass_, 12. The Walking Dead, 13. Babylon 5, 14. _Pass_, 15. _Pass_, 16. Red Dwarf, 17. _Pass_, 18. Supernatural, 19. Stargate: SG-1, 20. The Incredible Hulk (1978), 21. _Pass_, 22. Sabrina the Teenage Witch, 23. Quantum Leap, 24. Firefly

Comment: 1. TNG, 2. *Pass*, 3. Adventure Time, 4. Buffy, 5. Classic, 6. *Pass*, 7. LOST, 8. 60s, 9. *Pass*, 10. *Pass*, 11. Original, 12. GoT, 13. BSG, 14. Arrow, 15. *Pass*, 16. Farscape, 17. Daredevil, 18. OUaT, 19. SG1, 20. *Pass*, 21. Gravity Falls, 22. ALF, 23. Quantum Leap, 24. Firefly

Comment: 1. TNG 2. Futurama 3. My Little Pony 4. Buffy 5. Pass 6. Legend of Korra 7. X-Files 8. Batman TAS 9. Twilight Zone 10. Clone Wars 11. TMNT 12. TWD 13. BSG 14. Flash (The Jay Garrick show) 15. JLU 16. Pass 17. AoS 18. OUAT 19. I'm a friend of Sarah Connor 20. Pass 21. Pass 22. Pass 23. Quantum Leap 24. Firefly

Comment: 1) TNG; 2) Pass; 3) Adventure Time; 4) Angel; 5) New Who; 6) Pass; 7) LOST; 8) '60s; 9) Pass; 10) Pass; 11) Pass; 12) Game of Thrones; 13) Babylon 5; 14) Pass; 15) Pass; 16) Red Dwarf; 17) Pass; 18) Supernatural; 19) Stargate; 20) Hitchhiker's; 21) Gravity Falls; 22) Pass; 23) Torchwood; 24) Firefly.

Comment: 1) (write-in) ST-DS9; 2) Futurama; 5) Nu-Who; 10) Star Wars: Rebels; 16) Red Dwarf; 20) The Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Galaxy; 24) Firefly. Don't care or never seen the rest.

Comment: 1.Star Trek: The Next Generation 2.Futurama 3.Adventure Time 4.Pass 5.Nu-Who 6.Avatar: The Last Airbender 7.  X-Files 8. Batman: The Animated Series 9.The Outer Limits (Original) 10.Star Wars: The Clone Wars 11.TMNT (Original) 12.The Walking Deadm13.Babylon 5 14.Pass 15.Justice League Unlimited 16.Farscape 17.Pass 18.Pass 19.Stargate: SG-1 20.The Incredible Hulk (1978) 21.Gravity Falls 22.Sabrina the Teenage Witch 23.Torchwood 24.Firefly

Comment: 1: Star Trek: The Next Generation; 2. Futurama; 3. Adventure Time; 4. Buffy the Vampire Slayer; 5. Nu-Who; 6. Avatar: The Last Airbender; 7. X-Files; 8. Batman: The Animated Series; 9. The Twilight Zone; 10. Star Wars: Rebels; 11. TMNT; 12. Game of Thrones; 13. Babylon 5; 14. The Flash; 15. Justice League Unlimited; 16. Farscape; 17. Marvel's Agents of SHIELD; 18. Supernatural; 19. The Sarah Connor Chronicles; 20. The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy; 21. Transformers; 22. Sabrina the Teenage Witch; 23. Quantum Leap; 24. Firefly

Comment: 1. Star Trek: The Next Generation, 2. Futurama, 3. My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic, 4. Buffy the Vampire Slayer, 5. Nu-Who, 6. Avatar: The Last Airbender, 7. X-Files, 8. Batman: The Animated Series, 9. The Twilight Zone (Original), 10. Star Wars: The Clone Wars, 11. TMNT (Original), 12. Game of Thrones, 13. Battlestar Galactica (2004), 14. Arrow, 15. Justice League Unlimited, 16. Farscape, 17. Daredevil, 18. Pass, 19. The Sarah Connor Chronicles, 20. The Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Galaxy (TV series), 21. Transformers (1984), 22. ALF, 23. Quantum Leap, 24. Fringe

Comment: 1. Pass 2. Futurama 3. Adventure Time 4. Buffy the Vampire Slayer 5. New Who 6. Pass 7. X-Files 8. Pass 9. Pass 10. Pass 11. Pass 12. Game of Thrones 13. Pass 14. Arrow 15. Pass 16. Red Dwarf 17. Daredevil 18. Supernatural 19. Pass 20. Pass 21. Pass 22. Pass 23. Pass 24. Firefly

Comment: 1. TNG; 2.Futurama; 3. My Little Pony; 4. Pass; 5. Pass; 6.Avatar; 7. X-Files; 8. Pass; 9. Outer Limits; 10. Rebels; 11. Original; 12. Walking Dead; 13. Babylon 5; 14.Pass; 15.Pass; 16.Red Dwarf;17.Pass;18.Once upon a time; 19.SG1; 20.HHGTTG;21.Pass;22.Sabrina;23.Quantum Leap;24.Pass

Comment: 1. Pass, 2. Pass, 3. My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic, 4. Pass, 5. Pass, 6. Pass, 7. Pass, 8. Pass, 9. Pass, 10. Pass, 11. Pass, 12. Pass, 13. Pass, 14. Pass, 15. Pass, 16. Pass, 17. Pass, 18. Pass, 19. Pass, 20. Pass, 21. Pass, 22. Pass, 23. Pass, 24. Firefly.

Answer (score 1):

### Predictions are now over!

Comment: New Doctor Who!

Comment: My Little Pony. Not because it will win, but because it would be funny if it did.

Comment: While it's not my favorite, I predict *Star Trek: The Next Generation*. I won''t count my prediction, it's just for fun.

Comment: Daredevil should do it.

Comment: Game of thrones

Comment: Daredevil ! _Here are some chars to be able to post the comment -.-'_

Comment: I vote New Doctor Who. It's a great and world-wide-loved show, with lots of fans.

Comment: Buffy the Vampire Slayer

Comment: What ought to win: Firefly. What will actually win (probably): Game of Thrones. (Though as much as I despise, detest, hate, and abhor GRRM's writing, the TV show is surprisingly watchable.)

Comment: TNG will be the clear winner.

Comment: Batman: The Animated Series

Comment: Although I voted for TOS, I'm certain TNG will win.  Effortlessly.

Comment: _Firefly_, not because it's _necessarily_ the best on the list (although it might be), but down to the never-ending browncoat protest over moronic cancellations.

Comment: The winner is, and will ever be, Tom Baker.

Comment: TNG, based on our tags.

Comment: Firefly, as the common denominator of awesomeness.

Comment: Firefly (what @TonyMeyer said)

Comment: Batman: The Animated Series. Seems to have universal like on this site, and BECAUSE IT IS THE MUTHA' F_ING BATMAN!

Comment: Star Trek: The Original Series. That which is dead can never die... err.... it's Star Trek, original Trek. 'Nough said.

Comment: The winner will be *My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic* of course.

Comment: The new *Doctor Who*.