# The Great Science-Fiction/Fantasy TV Showdown! (Round 2) [Over]

Tags: discussion, contest, prizes

### This round is over! Round 3 and results are [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9628/the-great-science-fiction-fantasy-tv-showdown-round-3-back-with-a-vengeance?cb=1).

First off, please see the results from Round 1 and other important information on [this post](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/05/the-great-science-fictionfantasy-tv-showdown-results-and-round-two/) on our blog. You can also see Round 1 itself, [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9512/the-great-science-fiction-fantasy-tv-showdown-round-1-finished).

### To vote on your favorite show:

I will post and answer below. It will have all 12 primary brackets on it. Any site member with a SF&F SE account older than two weeks as of 5/2/2016 may vote. To do so, simply leave a single comment with the 12 shows you think are better. Put Pass and the bracket's number if you don't want to vote on a specific bracket. Attempting to vote more than once will result in none of your votes counting. **Upvoting someone's vote will not affect the outcome.** In one week, voting will close. I will see which twelve shows won their brackets and will post an update for Week Three.

**Please do not leave an answer on this page. If you have an additional question, comment, or gripe that your favorite show isn't on the list, please put it [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38884/the-great-science-fiction-fantasy-tv-showdown-discussion-room), or comment on the main question, not the voting answer.**

Have fun and May the Force be with you/ Live long and prosper/ Keep Flying/ Live together, die alone/ Cowabunga!/ Fear the Living, Fight the Dead...

Comment: Um, if this is a new meta for each round, then how does the prediction thing work? Is the prediction just for that round then? In this case, what makes a Nu-Who prediction better than a TNG prediction when both won? And how is the final prediction-winner going to be selected?

Comment: @TARS Neither won (yet). Prediction is just for the final winner and could only be guessed during Round 1.

Comment: Ah, ok. So you'll be deleting new comments on the prediction answer then?

Comment: @TARS  I'll just ignore them.

Comment: @anaranjada Just delete your comment and write a new one if you want. I don't mind.

Comment: @Randal'Thor No, 12 brackets means six winners.

Comment: @Randal'Thor You're right. I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Now all I need to do is write a best-selling children's fantasy series.

Comment: What is Nu-Who? Is that Doctor Who?

Comment: @dcshannon Revived (Post-2005) Doctor Who. Classic Doctor Who didn't get enough votes.

Comment: Just for clarity, a comment vote on the voting comments (if you get what I mean...) is meaningless, right?

Comment: @tonymeyer Yes, it does not affect the outcome.

Comment: Since people tend to have a hard time getting how this actually works, i.e. selecting one out of two for each bracket, you might want to explain that a little more throughly.

Comment: Did you post the vote counts from Round 1 somewhere?

Comment: @DCShannon http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/05/the-great-science-fictionfantasy-tv-showdown-results-and-round-two/

Comment: Are you still working on the actual Round 3 voting post? The link in the blog leads to the 404 page.

Answer (score 4):

1. **The Heavy Contenders #1:** *Star Trek: The Next Generation* and Nu-Who
2. **The Heavy Contenders #2:** *Game of Thrones* and *Firefly*
3. **Dave Filoni:** *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* and *Avatar: The Last Airbender*
4. **DC Animated:** *Justice League Unlimited* and *Batman: The Animated Series*
5. **Marvel VS DC:** *The Flash* and *Daredevil*
6. **Science Fiction with Numbers in their Names:** *Babylon 5* and *Stargate:
   SG-1*
7. **#80's:** *Transformers* (Original) and *TMNT* (Original)
8. **Animation Across the Nation(s), 2.0 Edition:** *Futurama* and *MLP:
   Friendship is Magic*
9. **Old School:** *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* (Series) and
   *Quantum Leap*
10. **90's and Beyond:** *Buffy the Vampire Slayer* and *The X-Files*
11. **Left-Overs (Part 1):** *Farscape* and *The Twilight Zone* (Original)
12. **Left-Overs (Part 2):** *Sabrina the Teenage Witch* and *Supernatural*

Comment: 1. TNG, 8. MLP, 9. Quantum Leap. Pass on the rest.

Comment: 1. Star Trek: The Next Generation, 2. Game of Thrones, 3. Pass, 4. Batman: The Animated Series, 5. Daredevil, 6. Pass, 7. TMNT (Original), 8. Futurama, 9. Quantum Leap, 10. Buffy the Vampire Slayer, 11. Pass, 12. Supernatural.

Comment: 1. Nu-Who 2. Game of Thrones 3. Pass 4. Justice League Unlimited 5. Daredevil 6. Babylon 5 7. Transformers 8. Futurama 9. Hitchhiker's Guide 10. Buffy 11. Twilight Zone 12. Pass

Comment: 1. Star Trek: The Next Generation,
2. Firefly,
3. Avatar: The Last Airbender
4. Justice League Unlimited 
5. The Flash, 6. Stargate: SG-1
6b. TMNT (Original)
7. Futurama, 8. The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (Series), 9.Buffy the Vampire Slayer,10. Farscape 
11. Supernatural

Comment: 1. TNG, 2. GoT, 3. Pass, 4. JLU, 5. Daredevil (anyone who votes for Flash hasn't seen Daredevil) 6. B5, 7. TMNT, 8. Futurama, 9. Quantum Leap, 10. X-Files, 11. Farscape, 12. Pass (haven't seen Supernatural, probably better)

Comment: 2. Game of Thrones 5. Daredevil 8. Futurama 10. Buffy 12. Sabrina - Pass on the rest.

Comment: 1. Nu-Who 2. Firefly 3. Star Wars: The Clone Wars 4. Pass 5. Daredevil 6. Pass 7.TMNT 8. Pass 9. Quantum Leap 10. Pass. 11. The Twilight Zone 12. Pass

Comment: 1. Nu-Who 2. Firefly 3. Avatar: The Last Airbender 4. Batman:TAS 5. Daredevil 6. Babylon 5 7. Transformers 8. Futurama 9. Quantum Leap 10. The X-Files 11. Twilight Zone 12. Sabrina the Teenage Witch

Comment: 1. Star Trek: The Next Generation 2. Firefly 3. Avatar: The Last Airbender 4. Justice League Unlimited 5. Daredevil 6. Stargate SG1 7. Transformers 8. Futurama 9. The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy 10. The X-Files 11. Farscape 12. Supernatural

Comment: 1) New Who. 2) Firefly. 3) Avatar. 4) Justice League Unlimited. 5) Pass. 6) Pass. 7) Pass. 8) MLP. 9) Hitchhiker's. 10) Buffy. 11) Pass. 12) Supernatural.

Comment: 1) DW, 2) GoT, 3) A:TLA, 4-7) pass, 8) Futurama, 9) THHGttG, 10) pass, 11) TTZ, 12) pass

Comment: 2. Firefly, 3. Star Wars: The Clone Wars, 5. The Flash, pass on the rest

Comment: 1. TNG, 2. Firefly, 3. Last Airbender, 4. Batman: TAS, 5. Flash (yes, I've seen Daredevil, still going with Flash), 6. B5, 7. TMNT, 8. Pass, 9. X-FRIGGIN'-FILES, 10. QLeap, 11. Twilight Zone, 12. Pass.

Comment: 1. DW (2005), 2. Firefly, 3. Pass, 4. Pass, 5. Daredevil, 6. SG1, 7. Transformers, 8. MLP:FiM, 9. Quantum Leap, 10. Buffy, 11. Farscape, 12. Pass

Comment: 1. Star Trek: The Next Generation, 2. Firefly, 3. Star Wars: The Clone Wars, 4. Batman: The Animated Series, 5. The Flash, 6. Stargate: SG-1, 7. TMNT (original), 8. MLP: Friendship is Magic, 9. Quantum Leap, 10. The X-Files, 11. Farscape, 12. Sabrina the Teenage Witch.

Comment: 1. Nu-Who 2. Game of Thrones 3. Avatar 4. Batman : TAS 5. Daredevil 6. SG1 7. TMNT 8. Futurama 9. Pass 10. Buffy 11. Pass 12. Supernatural

Comment: 1: Nu-Who, 2: Firefly, 3: Avatar: The Last Airbender, 4: Justice League Unlimited, 5: The Flash, 6: Stargate: SG-1, 7: TMNT (Original), 8: MLP: Friendship is Magic, 9: Quantum Leap, 10: Buffy the Vampire Slayer, 11: Farscape, 12: Sabrina the Teenage Witch

Comment: @TARS I actually haven't watched other shows. That's why I only picked my favorites. I can't judge between the twos in other categories. I mean I understand that I have to select one from each category in all the 12. Ah yes now that you mention the 'numbers wrong'. I see what's the problem. Okay. Here goes. 2. Game of Thrones, 5. Daredevil, 10. The X-Files

Comment: 1.Nu-Who. Pass the rest.

Comment: 1. New Who (I refuse to call it Nu-Who) 2. Firefly 3. Pass 4. Pass 5. Daredevil 6. Pass 7. Pass 8. Futurama 9. Pass 10. Buffy the Vampire Slayer 11. Pass 12. Supernatural

Comment: 1: Star Trek: The Next Generation
2: Firefly
3: Star Wars: The Clone Wars
4: Pass
5: Pass
6: Stargate: SG-1
7: TMNT
8: Futurama
9: The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy
10: Buffy the Vampire Slayer
11: Farscape
12: Sabrina the Teenage Witch

Comment: 1 Doctor Who 2 GOT 3 Clone Wars 4 Batman 5 Flash 6 SG-1 7 TMNT 8 Futurama 9 Hitchhiker's 10 X-Files 11 Twilight Zone 12 Sabrina

Comment: 1. Oy, tough one, but much as I love Picard, it's gotta be **Nu-Who**. 2. This one, on the other hand, is no contest: **Firefly**. 3. *Pass* 4. *Pass* 5. *Pass* 6. **Babylon 5** 7. *Pass* 8. *Pass* 9. **Hitchhiker's Guide**, because I can't stand that guy from Quantum Leap. 10. **Buffy**, no contest. 11. **Farscape**. 12. **Sabrina**.

Comment: 1. Nu-Who,  2. Firefly,  3. Star Wars: The Clone Wars,  4. Justice League Unlimited,  5. Daredevil,  6. Stargate: SG-1,  7. TMNT,  8. MLP: Friendship is Magic,  9. The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy,  10. Buffy the Vampire Slayer, 11. The Twilight Zone, 12. Supernatural

Comment: 2. Game of thrones, 3. Star Wars : Clone wars, 6. Babylon 5. pass on the rest

Comment: 1. **ST:TNG**, 2. GoT, 3.SW:Clone Wars, 4.pass, 5. Daredevil, 6. pass, 7. Transformers, 8. **Futurama**, 9. pass, 10. **Buffy**, 11. pass, 12. Sabrina

Comment: 1. TNG, 2. Firefly, 3. Pass, 4. Pass, 5. Daredevil, 6. Stargate SG-1, 7. TMNT, 8. Pass, 9. Quantum Leap, 10. X-Files, 11. Farscape, 12. Supernatural

Comment: 1. TNG
2. Firefly
3. Clone Wars
4. JLU
5. Flash
6. Pass
7. TMNT
8. Futurama
9. Quantum Leap
10. X-Files
11. Pass
12. Pass

Comment: 1. ST:tNG;  2. Firefly; 3. Clone Wars; 4. Batman; 5. Daredevil; 6.Babylon 5; 7. Transformers; 8. Futurama; 9. Quantum Leap; 10. X-Files; 11. Twilight Zone; 12. Supernatural.

Comment: 1. Nu-Who, 2. Firefly, 3.Star Wars: The Clone Wars, 4. JLU, 5. Daredevil, 6. Babylon 5, 7. Transformers, 8. Futurama, 9. Quantum Leap, 10. The X-Files, 11. Farscape, 12. Pass

Comment: 1. ST:TNG; 2. Firefly; 3. Avatar; 4. *pass*; 5. Daredevil; 6. Babylon5 (tough one); 7. *pass*; 8. *pass*; 9. Quantum Leap; 10. Buffy; 11. Farscape; 12. Supernatural

Comment: 1. Stark: The Next Generation; 2. Game of Thrones; 3. Star Wars: The Clone Wars; 4. Batman: The Animated Series; 5. The Flash; 6. Stargate SG-1; 7. TMNT; 8. Futurama; 9. Quantum Leap; 10. Buffy the Vampire Slayer; 11. The Twilight Zone; 12. Sabrina the Teenage Witch

Comment: 1. ST:TNG, 2. Firefly, 3. Star Wars, 4. pass, 5. The Flash, 6. B5, 7. TMNT, 8. MLP, 9. Quantum Leap, 10. Buffy, 11. Farscape, 12. Supernatural

Comment: 1 New Who 2 Firefly 3 Avatar 4 JLU 5 DD 6 SG1 7 TMNT 8 Futurama 9 QL 10 Buffy 11 Farscape 12 Supernatural

Comment: 1. TNG 2. GoT 3. Avatar 4. Pass 5. Pass 6. Babylon 5 7.Transformers 8. MLP 9.Quantum Leap 10. X files. 11. Farscape. 12. Sabrina

Comment: 1) Nu-*Doctor Who*   2) *Firefly*   3) Pass   4) *Batman: The Animated Series*   5) *Daredevil*   6) Pass   7) *TMNT*   8) *Futurama*   9) Pass   10) Pass   11) Pass   12) Pass

Comment: 1: TNG, 2: Firefly, 6: SG-1, 8: Futurama, 9: Quantum Leap.  Pass on the rest.

Comment: 1. TNG, 2. Firefly, 3. Avatar, 4. Batman, 8. Futurama, 10. The X-Files 11. The Twilight Zone, 12. Sabrina