# The Great Science-Fiction/Fantasy TV Showdown: Round 3: Back with a Vengeance! [Over!]

Tags: discussion, contest, prizes

### Round 3 is over! See Round 4 [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9688/51226)!

First, an explanation and an apology. This is not the original Round 3. The first version had different rankings, that in retrospect, were not the best. After multiple people expressed their views on it, I decided to start Round 3 over. Sorry for the poor choice and confusion, and hopefully this will go better the second time around.

Secondly, please see the results from Round 2 and other important information on [this post](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/05/the-great-science-fictionfantasy-tv-showdown-results-and-round-3-2nd-edition/) on our blog. You can also see Round 2 itself, [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9546/the-great-science-fiction-fantasy-tv-showdown-round-2-last-chance-to-enter).

### To vote on your favorite show:

I will post and answer below. It will have all six primary brackets on it. Any site member with a SF&F SE account older than two weeks as of 5/16/2016 may vote. To do so, simply leave a single comment with the six shows you think are better. Put Pass and the bracket's number if you don't want to vote on a specific bracket. Attempting to vote more than once will result in none of your votes counting. **Upvoting someone's comment will not affect the outcome.** In one week, voting will close. I will see which six shows won their brackets and will post an update for Round Four.

**Please do not leave an answer on this page. If you have an additional question, comment, or gripe that your favorite show isn't on the list, please put it [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38884/the-great-science-fiction-fantasy-tv-showdown-discussion-room), or comment on the main question, not the voting answer.**

Have fun and May the Force be with you/ Live long and prosper/ Keep Flying/ Live together, die alone/ Cowabunga!/ Fear the Living, Fight the Dead...

Comment: How did you determine the brackets this time?

Comment: @Richard Randomly. The blog post goes into more detail.

Comment: I trust you :-)

Comment: When does this round of voting end?

Comment: @anaranjada A week from today.

Comment: If we do another showdown like this later, maybe we could pick the top 16 shows/movies/franchises on the site based on tag count.

Comment: First time looking at one of these. Wouldn't it be easier to tabulate if there were 6 answers, and you voted up for one choice and down for the other?

Answer (score 6):

### VOTE!

1. *Buffy the Vampire Slayer* **vs.** *Daredevil*
2. *Stargate: SG-1* **vs.** *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*
3. *Firefly* **vs.** *Quantum Leap*
4. *Farscape* **vs.** *Star Trek: The Next Generation*
5. *Futurama* **vs.** *TMNT* (Original)
6. *Batman: The Animated Series* **vs.** *Supernatural*

Comment: 1. Daredevil 2. Star Wars: The Clone Wars 3. Firefly 4. Pass. 5. Pass 6. Batman: The Animated Series

Comment: 1. Buffy the Vampire Slayer; 2. Star Wars: The Clone Wars; 3. Firefly; 4. Star Trek: The Next Generation; 5. Futurama; 6. Batman: The Animated Series

Comment: 1. BtVS 2. SG-1 3. FF 4. Farscape 5. Futurama 6. Supernatural

Comment: 1. Daredevil 2. Stargate: SG-1 3. Firefly 4. Star Trek: The Next Generation 5. Futurama 6. Batman: The Animated Series

Comment: 1) *Daredevil* 2) Pass 3) *Firefly* 4) *Star Trek: The Next Generation* 5) *Futurama* 6) *Batman: The Animated Series*

Comment: 1. Daredevil, 2. Pass, 3. Firefly, 4. Star Trek: The Next Generation, 5. Futurama, 6. Batman: The Animated Series.

Comment: 1. Daredevil 2. SG1 3. Pass 4. Pass 5. Futurama 6. Supernatural.

Comment: 1. **Buffy**, 2. **Stargate**, 3. **Firefly**, 4. **TNG**, 5. Pass, 6. **Batman**

Comment: 1. Daredevil, 2. Clone Wars, 3. Firefly, 4. TNG, 5. Futurama, 6. Batman

Comment: 1. Daredevil, 2. SW: The Clone Wars, 3. Firefly, 4. ST:NG, 5. Futurama, 6. Batman: TAS

Comment: 1. Buffy  2. SG-1  3. Firefly  4. ST:TNG  5.  Futurama  6. Supernatural

Comment: 1) Buffy. 2) Stargate SG-1. 3) Pass. 4) Star Trek TNG. 5) Futurama. 6) Supernatural.

Comment: 1. **Buffy**, 2. **SG-1**, 3. **Firefly**, 4. **Farscape**, 5. *pass*, 6. **Supernatural**

Comment: 1)daredevil 2)Star Wars 3)quantum leap 4)Farscape 5)futurama 6)batman

Comment: 1. Buffy the Vampire Slayer
2. Stargate: SG-1
3. Firefly 4. 
Star Trek: The Next Generation
5. Futurama
6. Pass

Comment: 1. Daredevil 2. Star Wars: The Clone Wars 3. Firefly 4. Star Trek: The Next Generation 5. Futurama 6. Supernatural

Comment: 1. Daredevil, 2. Star Wars: The Clone Wars, 3.Firefly, *skip the rest*.

Comment: 1. Daredevil, 2. Star Wars, the Clone Wars, 3. Firefly, 4. Farscape, 5. Futurama, 6. Batman: the Animated Series

Comment: 1. Daredevil 2. SG-1 3. Firefly 4. TNG 5. Futurama 6. Batman

Comment: 1. Buffy, 2. SG-1, 3. QLeap, 4. TNG, 5. TMNT, 6. Batman.

Comment: 1. Daredevil. Pass on the rest.

Comment: 1. Buffy the Vampire Slayer, 2. Star Wars: The Clone Wars, 3. Firefly, 4. Farscape, 5. Futurama, 6. Batman: The Animated Series

Comment: 1. Daredevil, 6 .Batman: The Animated Series  Rest : Pass

Comment: 1. Daredevil 2. Pass 3. Firefly 4. Pass 5. Futurama 6. Supernatural

Comment: 1. Buffy, 2. pass, 3. Firefly, 4. TNG, 5. Futurama, 6. pass

Comment: 2. Stargate SG1 4. Star Trek: The Next Generation

Comment: 1. daredevil 2. stargate 4. startrek 5. futurama 6. batman

Comment: 1) Daredevil,  2) Clone Wars, 3) Pass, 4) TNG, 5) Futurama, 6) Batman

Comment: Buffy, SG-1, Firefly, TNG, Pass, Pass

Comment: 1. Daredevil, 2. SG1, 3. Firefly (by a hair), 4. TNG, 5. Futurama, 6. Batman

Comment: 1. Daredevil, 2. SG-1, 3. Firefly, 4. Star Trek: The Next Generation, 5. Futurama, 6. Supernatural

Comment: 1. Buffy the Vampire Slayer, 2. pass, 3. Quantum Leap!!!, 4. Star Trek: The Next Generation, 5: TMNT, 6: Batman: The Animated Series.

Comment: 1. Daredevil  2. Pass  3. Firefly 4. Pass 5. Futurama 6. Batman: The Animated Series

Comment: 1. Daredevil, 2. Star Wars: The Clone Wars, 3. Firefly, 4. ST:TNG, 5. Futurama, 6. Pass.