# The Great Science-Fiction/Fantasy TV Showdown: Round 4 [Over!]

Tags: discussion, support, contest

### This round is over! See the Final Round [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9725/51226)!

Please see the results from Round 3 and other important information on [this post](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/05/the-great-science-fictionfantasy-tv-showdown-round-4/?cb=1)  on our blog. You can also see Round 3 itself, [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9628/the-great-science-fiction-fantasy-tv-showdown-round-3-back-with-a-vengeance?cb=1).

To vote on your favorite show:

I will post an answer below. It will have all three primary brackets on it. Any site member with a SF&F SE account older than two weeks as of 5/23/2016 may vote. To do so, simply leave a single comment with the three shows you think are better. Put Pass and the bracket's number if you don't want to vote on a specific bracket. Attempting to vote more than once will result in none of your votes counting. **Upvoting someone's comment will not affect the outcome**. In one week, voting will close. I will see which three shows won their brackets and will post an update for the Final Round.

**Please do not leave an answer on this page. If you have an additional question, comment, or gripe that your favorite show isn't on the list, please put it [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38884/the-great-science-fiction-fantasy-tv-showdown-discussion-room), or comment on the main question, not the voting answer.**

Have fun and May the Force be with you/ Live long and prosper/ Keep Flying/ Live together, die alone/ Cowabunga!/ Fear the Living, Fight the Dead...

Comment: People: (once again, with feeling) **upvoting someone else's answer will NOT affect the outcome**. Please, please, please, post your own vote - upvoting mine will not help your favorite shows win!

Answer (score 4):

### Vote!

[image]

1. **Daredevil** VS **Star Trek: The Next Generation**
2. **Firefly** VS **Stargate: SG-1**
3. **Futurama** VS **Batman: The Animated Series**

**And remember, upvoting someone's comment does not effect anything!**

Comment: 1. TnG,  2. Firefly, 3. B:TaS

Comment: 1, tng  2. stargate 3. futurama

Comment: 1. TNG 2. Firefly 3. Futurama

Comment: 1. Daredevil, 2. Firefly, 3. Futurama.

Comment: 1. Daredevil, 2. Firefly, 3. Futurama

Comment: 1. TNG 2. Stargate 3. Futurama

Comment: 1. *Daredevil* 2. *Firefly* 3. *Futurama*

Comment: 1. Daredevil 2. Firefly 3. Pass

Comment: 1. DD 2. SG1 3. Futurama

Comment: 1. **TNG** 2. **Firefly** 3. **Batman**

Comment: 1. TNG, 2. Firefly, 3. Batman

Comment: 1. TNG, 2. Stargate SG-1, 3. Batman.

Comment: 1. TNG, 2. Stargate SG-1, 3. Futurama

Comment: 1. TNG 2. SG1 3. Batman

Comment: 1. TNG 2. Firefly 3. Futurama

Comment: 1. Daredevil 2. Firefly 3. Futurama

Comment: 1. DareDevil 2. SG1 3. Batman

Comment: TNG, Firefly, BAtman

Comment: 1. TNG; 2. Firefly; 3. Batman

Comment: 1.TNG, 2.Firefly, 3.Batman: The Animated Series

Comment: 1, tng 2. stargate 3. futurama

Comment: 1. Daredevil 2. Pass 3. Batman: The Animated Series

Comment: 1. TNG 2. Stargate SG-1 3. Batman

Comment: ***1. Daredevil | 2. Stargate SG-1 | 3. Batman***

Comment: TNG, Firefly, Pass

Comment: 1) TNG. 2) Firefly. 3) Pass.

Comment: 1. TNG 2. Firefly 3. Futurama

Comment: 1. TNG. 2. SG-1. 3. Batman.

Comment: 1. TNG. 2. Firefly. 3. BTAS.

Comment: 1. Daredevil, 2. Firefly, *Pass on the rest.*

Comment: 1. Daredevil, 2. Firefly, 3. Batman

Comment: 1. TNG; 2. Firefly; 3. Futurama

Comment: 1. TNG, 2. pass, 3. Batman

Comment: 1. TnG, 2. Firefly, 3. B:TaS

Comment: 1. TNG, 2. Firefly. 3. Batman

Comment: 1. TNG, 2. Firefly, 3. Pass

Comment: 1. TNG, 2. Firefly, 3. Futurama

Comment: 1. TNG, 2. Stargate, 3. Batman

Comment: 1. TNG, 2. Pass, 3. Pass

Comment: 1. Daredevil, 2. Firefly, 3. pass