# The Great Science-Fiction/Fantasy TV Showdown: The Final Round [Over!]

Tags: discussion, contest, prizes

### It's over! Final results are [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9764/51226)!

Please see the results from Round 4 and other important information on [this post](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/05/the-great-science-fictionfantasy-tv-showdown-final-round/?cb=1) on our blog. You can also see Round 4 itself, [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9688/51226).

To vote on your favorite show:

I will post an answer below. It will have the bracket on it. Any site member with a SF&F SE account older than two weeks as of 5/30/2016 may vote. To do so, simply leave a single comment with the single show you think is better. Attempting to vote more than once will result in none of your votes counting. **Upvoting someone's comment will not affect the outcome**. In one week, voting will close. I will see which show won and post an update.

Please do not leave an answer on this page. If you have an additional question, comment, or gripe that your favorite show isn't on the list, please put it [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38884/the-great-science-fiction-fantasy-tv-showdown-discussion-room), or comment on the main question, not the voting answer.

Thanks to everyone who's participated, and let's go out with a bang!

Comment: Aww, was gunning for Daredevil. Oh well, it had a good run!

Comment: I can't help but wonder how much influence, if any, the *Answerama* contest of 2012 had on *Batman: The Animated Season* winning....

Comment: I've just seen the first episode of *Firefly*. Can I change my vote?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Sure. Just make sure to delete your original comment. (I see that *Firefly* has worked its magic quickly.)

Comment: @armadillo *TNG* is boringness in space, which is too British for me.

Answer (score 13):

### VOTE!

**Firefly** VS **Star Trek: The Next Generation** VS **Batman: The Animated Series**

Comment: Firefly..........

Comment: **TNG.  Make it so.**

Comment: **TNG.** Shut up, Wesley!

Comment: Show like this, be with you 'til the day you die. I choose **Firefly**.

Comment: Batman: The Animated Series - I am vengeance! I am the night! I AM BATMAN!

Comment: **Firefly** ...

Comment: **Batman** FTW!

Comment: Take my love.
Take my land.
Take me where I cannot stand.
I don't care,
I'm still free.
You can't take the **Firefly** from me.

Comment: __Batman__ It has to be.

Comment: Firefly..................

Comment: Star Trek: The Next Generation

Comment: Obviously Firefly.

Comment: Star Trek: Then Next Generation.

Comment: Batman: The Animated Series.

Comment: Firefly. Reluctantly.

Comment: Batman: The Animated Series.... Because you don't mess with the Motha' Effing Batman!

Comment: Batman: TAS hands down.

Comment: TNG. These are The Voyages...

Comment: Star Trek: The Next Generation. (cause I typo'ed the first one, it's deleted)

Comment: Batman The Animated Series

Comment: **Firefly** for sure

Comment: Star Trek: The Next Generation

Comment: TNG. I gotta get my bet bounty, here!

Comment: Firefly, for the writing. I give TNG an honorable mention, for the Borg.

Comment: Batman: The Animated Series. Do i need to write it with my blood O.o

Comment: Firefly........

Comment: Firefly...............

Comment: Firefly........

Comment: TNG............

Comment: ST:TNG.  Just don't tell my sister I didn't vote for B:TAS...

Comment: Star Trek: The Next Generation

Comment: TNG: Make it so

Comment: **Firefly**. (I want to *live* in TNG's world, but I want to *watch* **Firefly** while I do so. Anybody up for some Firefly reenactment on the holodeck?)

Comment: None of these shows has Tom Baker in them. Abstained.

Comment: Firefly .. it is

Comment: Firefly.........

Comment: Star Trek The Next Generation

Comment: **Firefly!**  “May have been the losing side. Still not convinced it was the wrong one.”

Comment: Firefly!7654321

Comment: Firefly (not just because it was my original prediction!)

Comment: **TNG**. While Firefly was good, not managing to attain more seasons than they did killed it for me.

Comment: **BTAS** for being so hugely influential in its genre.

Comment: If you don't vote for *Firefly*, you're going to burn in a very special level of hell. A level they reserve for child molesters and people who talk at the theater. So ***Firefly*** it is.

Comment: **ST: TNG**. I immensely enjoined Firefly, but it was over too soon. A couple more seasons would have made this a more difficult choice.

Comment: **TNG** because 176 awesome episodes beats 14.

Comment: TNG, because if it weren't for TNG, I would be here!

Comment: **Firefly**. They can't take the sky from us!

Comment: Star Trek : TNG

Comment: http://cdn-static.denofgeek.com/sites/denofgeek/files/2015/10/batman-yellow-west.jpg

Comment: **Star Trek: The Next Generation**

Comment: ***Firefly!***..

Comment: Batman: The Animated Series

Comment: **Firefly**, given that there are no stated criteria for the choice. ST:TNG would win given some criteria whereas Firefly would with other criteria. Overall, even through Firefly had a much shorter run, the stories/writing made me care more for the characters than ST:TNG. Perhaps this is in part due to it being produced closer to now than ST:TNG, but even at the time it was more about the characters than it was the situation external to the characters.

Comment: **Batman**: The Animated Series...

Comment: Firefly.... Hands down the best show.... and that leather coat!!!!

Comment: How is this even a question... Firefly!

Comment: Star Trek: TNG.  Today is a good day to vote!

Comment: As much as I love Firefly, Serenity felt like to much of a rush job to be a fan service and to tie up loose ends.  I'm going to have to vote for **ST:TNG**.

Comment: Having now started watching **Firefly**, I'm going to have to change my vote. Sorry, TNG: Captain Reynolds > Captain Picard. *Take my rep, take my badge, take me where I cannot vote - I don't care, I'm still free...*

Comment: @Randal'Thor : [**RAAAAAAAAAAND!  RAAAAAAAAAAND!**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajsNJtnUb7c)

Comment: @Praxis [I'm sorry. I'm so sorry.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHVW-S9JkKA)

Comment: @armadillo To be fair, I haven't affected the outcome, only how close it was.

Comment: @armadillo And Star Trek isn't American? :-) If it had been Firefly vs Doctor Who, I'd have voted for DW in an instant, I assure you. (Chat seems to be fixed by now, btw.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor : As a fellow Brit, I ask (out of pure curiosity): would you always prefer one series or film over another because one is British?  I guess it's alien to me because I have almost always preferred American series and films over British ones, but not for any other reason than enjoying them more.

Comment: @Randal'Thor : Case in point, while I love *Who*, you can guess where I fall on the *Who* vs. *Trek* question.

Comment: @Praxis No, not at all. There are a lot of things I would consider 'too American', but I certainly wouldn't rule anything out just for being American, and there's crap produced in Britain too :-) I suppose if it's a choice between a BBC TV series and a Hollywood film, I would be prejudiced in favour of the former ... but I love *Stardust*, for instance.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Recency bias!

Comment: @Ellesedil True ... but like I said before, I didn't affect the final outcome by changing my mind :-)

Comment: @DrRDizzle You said "theater" and not "theatre"? Is that treason?