# The Great Science-Fiction/Fantasy TV Showdown: The Winner!

Tags: discussion, contest, prizes

Here we are.

The end of this great journey.

Many worthy series fell, but three remain.

Until now.

*Firefly*, *Star Trek: The Next Generation* and *Batman: The Animated Series* all fought well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

But one fought the best.

### 3

### 2

### 1

[image]

### FIREFLY WINS!

**Final Scores:**

*Firefly*: **26**

*Star Trek: The Next Generation*: **22**

*Batman: The Animated Series*: **11**

And now for the prize!

Captain Cranium, Tony Meyer and Jeeped all correctly predicted *Firefly*, so we'll have to determine the winner randomly.

Whoever is at the top of the generated list wins.

[image]

[image]

Tony Meyer wins! He'll get his bounty soon.

Thanks to all the mods and users who helped and participated!

[image]

Comment: And yes, I do know that that destroyed Enterprise isn't from *The Next Generation*.

Comment: We've done the impossible, and that makes us mighty. We are just too pretty for God to let us die.

Comment: I suggest you award the bounty to [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2000/what-was-in-the-syringe-that-inara-had-in-the-pilot-episode/2011#2011).

Comment: I inspired at least one person to watch *Firefly* so this was definitely worthwhile.

Comment: Everyone is getting into *Firefly* these days. Easterly Irk started on the same day as me, and Ankit Sharma is about to start too.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm fine with just the glory of being right and without the bounty. If you want to give it to me, that's fine, but also fine if you want to find somewhere else it deserves to be.

Comment: http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120131203323/memoryalpha/en/images/b/b8/USS_Enterprise-D_explodes,_2368.jpg

Comment: @TonyMeyer You can always give out your own bounty! Share the love

Comment: I demand a recount.

Comment: The implication here is that each episode of Firefly is worth 12.57 episodes of Star Trek: TNG. This is preposterous. Make it not so!

Comment: @DCShannon You're right. It should probably be higher.

Comment: @TonyMeyer Alright, if you feel that way, I'll use it for something else.